# Loading an excle sheet with dato only returns only None when using openpyxl

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

i Use Openpyxl to import data from a  excle sheet und it dosnt let me import values of these formulas
To test if i turn of data only it returnes all the formulas perfektly but as soon as thats turnend on i only get None even thow when i open my excle sheet i can see data in exactally these cellls.
the same allso holds true if i try the same thing with pandas

```
# Laden der Excel-Datei mit data_only=True
ws = load_workbook(dateipfad, data_only=True)

# Zugriff auf das gewünschte Blatt
blatt = ws[blattname]

# Ausgabe der Zeilen 40 bis 44
for zeile in blatt.iter_rows(min_row=40, max_row=44):
    zeilenwerte = [zelle.value for zelle in zeile]
    print(zeilenwerte)

# Schließen der Arbeitsmappe
ws.close()
```

and my retun is :
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

i tryed a lot of things now and nothing helped ... i just want the values to be returned
and it´s the same problem for pandas

Comment: I guess the cells have formulae that have never been evaluated.